# Error :Specified argument was out of the range of valid values. Parameter name: index in Rad Grid Exopt to excel

Tags: vb.net, export-to-excel, radgrid

Am getting error Specified argument was out of the range of valid values.
Parameter name: index

When am trying to export to excel .

here is my code

```
  Protected Sub btnExportExcel_Click(sender As Object, e As ImageClickEventArgs)
    Try
        If goGrid.MasterTableView.Items.Count > 0 Then
            goGrid.ExportSettings.FileName = goView.Title.Replace(" ", "_")
            goGrid.MasterTableView.Columns(0).Visible = False
            goGrid.MasterTableView.Columns(goGrid.MasterTableView.Columns.Count - 1).Visible = False
            goGrid.ExportSettings.OpenInNewWindow = False
            For Each item As GridDataItem In goGrid.MasterTableView.Items
                If item.Cells.Count < goGrid.MasterTableView.Columns.Count Then
                    item.Visible = False
                End If
            Next
            'goGrid.ExportSettings.IgnorePaging = False
           ' goGrid.ExportSettings.OpenInNewWindow = False
            goGrid.MasterTableView.ExportToExcel()
        End If
    Catch ex As Exception
        If Not ex.Message = clC.EX_THREAD_ABORT_MESSAGE Then
            goErr.SetError(ex, , "")
        End If
    End Try
End Sub
```

Export to PDF is working fine

```
Protected Sub goGrid_ExcelExportCellFormatting(sender As Object, e As ExcelExportCellFormattingEventArgs)
    Dim s As String = e.Cell.Text
End Sub
```

in above ExcelExportCellFormatting looping is done only 4 times after 5th loop am getting above error .am not getting

Comment: On which line does your error occur?

Comment: After ExcelExportCellFormatting looping 4 times it is redirecting to error page

Comment: I don't see a loop in `goGrid_ExcelExportCellFormatting()`. What calls this Sub?

Comment: when i debug my code after goGrid.MasterTableView.ExportToExcel() this debugging point to going to goGrid_ExcelExportCellFormatting() this method .Is in not calling goGrid_GridExporting or this goGrid_PdfExporting